# Referencing to a specific View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

My app works such that when a notification is received, it will place it into a `UITableView`. I have done it in another project which has a navigation controller and uses a `TableViewController`. However, this time, I am not using a `navigationcontroller` and the `TableView` does not get the text because I did not refer to it in the `AppDelegate.m`.

In my previous project (where I used a navigation controller), I used this code to reference to the correct VC:

```
// Reference to Push notifs List VC
self.pnListVC = (apnListVC *)[[(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Since I am not using a `navigationcontroller` this time, can someone advise me on what code to use instead?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your TableViewController is the root ViewController, you can access it simply by

```
self.window.rootViewController
```

and cast it as required.

Eg:

```
self.tableVC = (CustomTableViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
```

where **CustomTableViewController** will be the class name of your TableViewController